Trying to download m3u8/HLS stream, but FFmpeg is dropping the auth token after each .ts link
Command:
ffmpeg -i "https://example.com/path/to/playlist.m3u8?token=your_token_here" -c copy output.mp4

The .m3u8 contains a list of .ts files. FFmpeg is supposed to replace the .m3u8 in the URL with each .ts filename, creating a URL to where each .ts file is stored on the server.
However for me, it's skipping the auth token at the end. Then I just get repeated 403 Forbidden errors because it can't access the URLs.
How do I force FFmpeg to include the token before trying to open the links?

Try passing the token another way : -headers "Authorization: Bearer <your_token>" but tokens have, often, a limited lifetime. Refresh them.

Download it first.  wget "https://example.com/path/to/playlist.m3u8?token=token", then ffmpeg can run it locally without issue.
